# Get value of JSON

Tags: json, node.js, sqlite

So, I have looked all over the internet for a solution to this, and have found none.

I am using NodeJS to get the output of a SQLite query and then act on it. The exact JSON returned is

> { 'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE teamnum=1234 LIMIT 1)': 0 }

and the output can be a 1 or a 0. In the example above it is a 0. I want to get that 1 or 0. Any ideas?

Comment: `obj['EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE teamnum=1234 LIMIT 1)']` where `obj` is returned object after parsing JSON to JavaScript object.

Comment: So you have a JSON string? Can you not just use s = JSON.parse(yourstring.replace(/'/g,'"')); for (var key in s) { console.log(s[key] } ?

Comment: @Nonemoticoner Sorry, but that just returns "undefined", and if I try to parse it I get the good old "o error" because it is already parsed JSON.

Comment: @user234461 it is not a string it is returned as an obj.

Comment: s = yourjsonobject; for (var key in s) { console.log(key); console.log(s[key]) } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you really have that object with data - this will work:

```
var obj = {'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data WHERE teamnum=1234 LIMIT 1)':0};
var ans = parseInt(JSON.stringify(obj).match(/:(.*?)}/)[1]);
```

Where `ans` will be equal to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

So i just decided to change my SQLite query to make SQLite figure out the logic instead of making node do it.

P.S. The above answer did work for my code.